# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)"

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am changing my Flask database from sqlite to MySQL but it's failing to connect, I am able to login to the database using Datagrip but it's not connecting in my flask app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app_context = app.app_context()
app_context.push()


# app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///db.sqlite"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:pass@localhost:3306/horizon_db'
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "abc"
app.config['ENV'] = 'development'
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['TESTING'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

Comment: You could try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: are you sure that you are using pymysql at all

Comment: your needs for that a `import pymysql`

Comment: @GordThompson I have tried that same thing

Comment: @nbk well I installed it

Comment: that is not enough to access it you need tp import it

Comment: @nbk how do i do that

Comment: see my previous comment

Comment: @nbk it's giving same error

Comment: i run your code in vs code and it connects with pymysql to my server, have you connected  to the server with workbench for testing purposes

Comment: @nbk - Using `mysql+pymysql://` does not normally require an explicit `import pymysql`

Comment: @nbk yes it's showing in MySQL workbench

Comment: @GordThompson i run the code with python 3.11.4 and renied all packages, it still runs, so the problem isn't the code or the import pymysql, localhost open on windows a pipe connection, if it fails it tries tcp/ip, as workbench works, eventually tried with mysqclient

Comment: @GordThompsonso the issue is the mysql setup yeah??